# Library fails to import on AppEngine in production, but succeeds in dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm using a library that imports `from six.moves.urllib.parse import parse_qs`.

On dev_appserver (`http://localhost:8000/console`), `parse_qs` can be imported successfully.

But when I deploy my app, I get the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/standalone:1.379863578027987467/modules/standalone/gapi/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from modules.standalone.gapi.v1.endpoints import xero
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/standalone:1.379863578027987467/modules/standalone/gapi/v1/endpoints/xero.py", line 9, in <module>
    from xero.api import Xero
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/standalone:1.379863578027987467/xero/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .manager import Manager
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/standalone:1.379863578027987467/xero/manager.py", line 7, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.parse import parse_qs
ImportError: No module named urllib.parse
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not do `from urlparse import parse_qs`

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing as a workaround, by modifying the library source. It sucks though since I'm using the master branch of the library, so when updates come in I'll have to remember to redo the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you install this library in your local machine  trhought PIP, but in app engine you need copy the code (see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) in the section "Adding Third Party Python Libraries"
By example i use the rauth library so, i  had to copy the .py files inside the app folder, but in your case the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/six/index.html#module-six) says

> six consists of only one Python file

so there should be no problem

ps. if you use folders don't forget the **init**.py file

Comment: Ah no, I "install" libraries by pasting them directly into the project root (not via pip). In fact, I'm pretty sure there are other libraries that I already use also depending on six, and I didn't have this issue. I found this [Bitbucket thread](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/pull-request/5/create-sixmovesurllib/diff), but it's old and since it's working locally I don't think it's relevant?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0 which I think is the latest version.